# How to limit the domain that is allowed to access an azure resource

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I write an app next js and deployed to vercel . however I used azure service called azure open ai . In the request I send on azure open ai in the header of the request contains the api key . I don't want the user to be able to get this api key and access the azure open ai by themselves. so i want to restrict by domain can access to azure open ai . please show me how to do it

Comment: some body help me

Answer (score 1):

OpenAI service has limited accessibility at this time, but from what I've been able to glean from [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189789/azure-openai-service-required-url-for-firewall) the resource configuration is common to the [Cognitive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-virtual-networks#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range) family and so supports configuring IP address restrictions and private vnet connectivity. If your calling service has a fixed IP, this should be sufficient, but you could also consider [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) for awareness of DNS names as frontend filtering criteria.